# Wann benutzt man normalen Passiv und Zustandpassiv?

Tags: passive

Ich habe eine blöde Frage. Ich habe Schwierigkeiten mit der Verwendung des normalen Passiv und Zustandpassiv. 
Was ist der Unterschied, kann ich nicht verstehen. 
z. B. Der Rasen ist gemäht oder der Rasen wird gemäht. 
In meinem Lehrbuch ist geschrieben, dass mit "wird" richtig ist. Warum kann ich nicht "ist" benutzen? 
Erklären Sie, bitte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Bedeutung ist etwas anders.

> Der Rasen wird gemäht.

bedeutet, dass gerade jemand mit dem Rasenmäher arbeitet.

> Der Rasen ist gemäht.

kommt danach, wenn der Rasenmäher fertig ist.

Comment: *Das Mädchen wird frisiert* heißt insbesondere, dass es sich nicht selbst frisiert, sondern das jemand anders macht. Das kommt bei Rasen nicht in Frage, ist aber der wichtigere Aspekt der Passivkonstruktion.

Comment: @guidot Guter Punkt. Mach doch eine Antwort draus?

Answer (score 1):

Beides ist richtig, aber die beiden Sätze bedeuten verschiedene Dinge:

- **Vorgangspassiv**
  Ein Vorgang (eine Veränderung) wird beschrieben:

  > Der Rasen wird gemäht.
- **Zustandspassiv**
  Ein Zustand (keine Veränderung) wird beschrieben:

  > Der Rasen ist gemäht.

Das Wort *»gemäht«* ist ein Partizip (Partizip II), das ist ein Mittelding aus Verb und Adjektiv. Im Vorgangspassiv ist es noch eindeutig ein Verb, das ist im Zustandspassiv nicht mehr so klar. Man kann das Partizip nämlich auch als prädikativ verwendetes Adjektiv intepretieren. (Mehr darüber hier: [Partizip II: Verb oder Adjektiv?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36241/partizip-ii-verb-oder-adjektiv))