# Why is »der stärksten Gravitationswirkung unterworfen ist« not »der stärksten Gravitationswirkung unterworfen wird«

Tags: passive, auxiliary-verb

Would this not be a passive construction?
Full context from *Eine kurze Geschichte der Zeit* by Stephen Hawking:

> Im Falle des Merkur jedoch, der – von allen Planeten der Sonne am
>   nächsten – der stärksten Gravitationswirkung unterworfen ist und eine
>   entsprechend längliche Umlaufbahn hat, prognostiziert die allgemeine
>   Relativitätstheorie, daß die lange Achse der Ellipse sich mit einer
>   Geschwindigkeit von ungefähr einem Grad pro zehntausend Jahren um die
>   Sonne drehen müßte.

Comment: Related http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/35383/wann-benutzt-man-normalen-passiv-und-zustandpassiv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like the German translation and would choose instead:

> der stärksten Gravitationswirkung unterliegt

*Unterwerfen* has a strong action connotation, which is not appropriate here, and which is also part of the reason, why *unterworfen wird* is not a good choice here.

Nobody does anything to expose Mercure to gravitation, it is simply a state (applicable since Mercure exists), why *Zustandpassiv* (and therefore *unterworfen ist*) is a convincing grammatical choice.

Comment: That's right, I sometimes get confused after switching between languages for a long time and forgot that construction exists in German.

Comment: This does not answer the question of whether it should be *werden* or *sein.*

Answer (score 4):

German has two different types of passive voice:

- Zustandspassiv (stative passive)
- Vorgangspassiv (dynamic passive)

I show you with shorter sentences:

### Zustandspassiv

> Der Planet **ist** der Schwerkraft unterworfen.
>   The planet is subject to gravity.

This is the description of a state (state = *Zustand* in German). Nothing is happening here. This is just the description of how it is.

### Vorgangspassiv

> Der Planet **wird** der Schwerkraft unterworfen.
>   The planet is subjected to gravity.

This is the description of an process (process = *Vorgang*). Here we are watching how something is changing. The planet was not subjected to gravity in the past, but it will be in the future, and now this change is going on.