# Partizip II: Verb oder Adjektiv?

Tags: verb, adjective, participle, word-classes

Das Wort »aufgeräumt« kann als Adjektiv aufgefasst werden:

Verwendung als Attribut eines Nomens in einer Nominalphrase:

> Du lebst in einer **aufgeräumten** Wohnung.

Steigerung (Komparativ):

> Deine Wohnung ist **aufgeräumter** als meine. (prädikativ)
>   Du wohnst in der **aufgeräumteren** Wohnung. (attributiv)

Steigerung (Superlativ):

> Deine Wohnung ist **am aufgeräumtesten**. (prädikativ)
>   Das hier ist die **aufgeräumteste** Wohnung. (attributiv)

---

Es kann aber auch ein Verb sein:

Partizip II von »aufräumen«:

> Ich habe das Zimmer **aufgeräumt**. (Perfekt)
>   Deine Wohnung wird **aufgeräumt**. (Vorgangspassiv)

---

Bis hierher ist alls klar. Aber welcher Wortart gehört »aufgeräumt« im folgenden Satz an?

> Deine Wohnung ist **aufgeräumt**.

Ist *aufgeräumt* hier ein Adjektiv, das prädikativ verwendet wird, was man z.B daran erkennen könnte, dass das Adjektiv an dieser Stelle gesteigert werden kann?

> Deine Wohnung ist **aufgeräumt**. (Positiv)
>   Deine Wohnung ist **aufgeräumter**. (Komparativ)
>   Deine Wohnung ist **am aufgeräumtesten**. (Superlativ)

Vergleichbar mit

> Deine Wohnung ist **groß**.
>   Deine Wohnung ist **größer**.
>   Deine Wohnung ist **am größten**.

Oder ist »aufgeräumt« hier das Partizip II von »aufräumen«, also ein Verb, das in einer Passiv-Konstruktion verwendet wird?

> Deine Wohnung wird **aufgeräumt**. (Vorgangspassiv)
>   Deine Wohnung ist **aufgeräumt**. (Zustandspassiv)

Vergleiche mit:

> Deine Wohnung wird **versperrt**.
>   Deine Wohnung ist **versperrt**.

---

Wie ist das, wenn das (vermeintliche) Adjektiv nicht prädikativ, sondern adverbiell verwendet wird?

> Deine Wohnung wirkt **aufgeräumt**.

Hier ist eine Steigerung ja noch immer möglich:

> Deine Wohnung wirkt **aufgeräumter**.
>   Deine Wohnung wirkt **am aufgeräumtesten**.

Ist in dem nicht gesteigerten Satz eine Deutung als Partizip II eines Verbs noch immer möglich?

Ist die adverbielle Verwendung von »aufgeräumt« (und vielen vergleichbaren Wörtern) tatsächlich der einzige Fall, in dem das Adjektiv in seiner undeklinierten Grundform in einem deutschen Satz vorkommt, und dabei nicht als Verb angesehen werden kann?

Comment: Was spricht dagegen, zu sagen, dass es beides sein kann? Die grammatische Struktur ist hier halt ambig...

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ich weis es nicht. Spricht etwas dagegen? Wenn nicht, dann wäre das ja vielleicht eine Antwort. (Falls du eine Antwort schreiben willst, gehe bitte auch auf den allerletzten Absatz meiner Frage ein.)

Comment: Ich würde sagen, im Satz "Deine Wohnung ist aufgeräumt" ist die grammatische Struktur ambig. Da die grammatische Struktur den Sinn aber leicht verändert, könnte ich mir vorstellen, dass man mit entsprechenden Kontexten "aufgeräumt" einmal eher als Verb, ein ander mal eher als Adjektiv sehen würde. Ich bastle gerade noch an den entsprechenden Kontexten... Die letzte Frage kann ich nicht beantworten. Ich tendiere zu "Ja", aber beweisen lässt sich sowas immer schlecht, und ich habe zu wenig Ahnung, um das definitiv sagen zu können.

Comment: Stimme zu. Ein adjektivisch verwendetes Partizip im Positiv und ein Zustandspassiv kann man nicht auseinanderhalten. Alleine, wenn du Komparativ oder Superlativ verwendest, kann es wohl kein Zustandspassiv mehr sein, sondern ist ein neues Adjektiv, das aus dem Partizip entstanden ist. Und weil es dieselbe Form ist, kann man es eben immer noch nicht auseinanderhalten. MMn sind das aber zwei verschiedene Sätze mit unterschiedlichen Wörtern, die halt zufällig gleich aussehen.

Answer (score 2):

Ein Partizip ist per Definition ein verbales Adjektiv. Die Frage lässt sich also nicht sinnvoll beantworten.

Comment: Nein. Ein Partizip ist per Definition eine Verbform und *kann adjektivisch verwendet werden*. Das ist was anderes.

Comment: Gewiss werden Partizipien aus Verben gebildet, aber sie sind eben nicht Verben, sondern Adjektive. Es handelt sich um deverbale Adjektive, deren Bildungsweise fix grammatikalisiert ist. Zumindest aus typologischer Sicht. Ihre Verwendung ist wiederum stark grammatikalisiert.