# Zu welcher Kategorie gehört das Partizip II, zu den Hilfs- oder Vollverben?

Tags: participle

ob das Partizip II in die Kategorie der Hilfs- oder Vollverben zugeordnet wird. Ich bin der der Meinung das diese zu den Hilfsverben gehören, da sie den Nutzen der Vollverben alleine nicht vollbringen können. Trotzdem bin ich mir unsicher und frage lieber nach. Zum Beispiel bei dem Satz:

> Ich habe gespielt oder ich werde gegessen haben.

Hier sind *»haben«*, das Partizip II und *»werden«* die Hilfsverben und es gibt keine Vollverben richtig?

Falls ich irgendwo falsch liege würde ich mich sehr über eine Rückmeldung freuen.

Answer (score 4):

Ein Partizip ist eigentlich überhaupt kein Verb - es ist zwar von einem Verb abgeleitet, hat aber ansonsten alle Eigenschaften eines Adjektivs.

Deswegen ist die Frage eigentlich nicht besonders sinnvoll zu beantworten, oder nur so: Ein Partizip ist kein Hilfs- und kein Vollverb, sondern gar kein Verb mehr. Es hat (fast) alle Eigenschaften eines Adjektivs und kann nur mit einem Hilfsverb ein Prädikat bilden.

Oder anders ausgedrückt: Ein *Hilfs*verb ist deswegen ein Hilfsverb, weil es einem Partizip *helfen* kann, trotz seiner adjektivischen Eigenschaften wieder ein Prädikt zu bilden.

Answer (score 2):

Das Partizip II ist kein Verb, sondern eine *Verbform*. Daher ergibt die Frage, ob es zu den Hilfs- oder Vollverben gehört, keinen Sinn.

Das Partizip II kann sowohl von Voll- als auch von Hilfsverben gebildet werden. Von Hilfsverben wird es allerdings eher selten gebildet, siehe unten.

Im Satz

> Ich habe gespielt

ist *gespielt* das Partizip II des Vollverbs *spielen*.

Im Satz

> Ich werde gegessen haben

ist *gegessen* das Partizip II des Vollverbs *essen*. *Haben* ist kein Partizip II, sondern ein Infinitiv.

Das Partizip II von Hilfsverben tritt nur selten auf, da es in den elementaren deutschen Tempusformen keine Verwendung findet.

Es tritt auf in der Kombination von Perfekt und Passiv:

> Gestern ist Fußball gespielt worden.

Hier ist *gespielt* das Partizip II des Vollverbs *spielen* und *worden* ist das Partizip II des Hilfsverbs *werden*.

Es gibt außerdem eine dialektale Variante des Plusquamperfekts, in der *haben* als Partizip II auftreten kann:

> Ich hab(e) gegessen gehabt.

(Dialektale Variante von Standarddeutsch *Ich hatte gegessen*)

Hier ist *gehabt* tatsächlich das Partizip II des Hilfsverbs *haben*.

Comment: "Morgen um diese Uhrzeit werden wir bereits die Mathe-Prüfung gehabt haben." Ist nicht dialektal, verwendet aber das Partizip eines Hilfsverbs.

Comment: Ob *haben* in *Wir haben Mathe-Prüfung* wirklich ein Hilfsverb ist, habe ich meine Zweifel. Ich würde eher sagen, es handelt sich um eine spezielle Verwendung von *haben* als Vollverb.

Answer (score 0):

Die Wortkategorie hat nichts mit der Flektion zu tun. Da "essen" ein Vollverb ist, ist auch "gegessen" ein Vollverb - nämlich eine andere Form desselben Vollverbs. Umgekehrt ist "sein" ein Hilfsverb und daher auch "gewesen".

Comment: *Sein* kann sowohl Voll- als auch Hilfsverb sein.

Comment: Nun "essen" ist sicher ein Vollverb. Das Partizip "gegessen" ist ein Partizip eines Vollverbs, aber kein Verb mehr.

Answer (score 0):

Hilfsverben werden benötigt, um bestimmte grammatischen Zeiten bilden zu können. Es gibt im Deutschen genau 3 Verben, die man dafür verwenden kann:

- **haben**

> Ich **habe** geschlafen.

- **sein**

> Ich **bin** eingeschlafen.

- **werden**

> Ich **werde** schlafen.

Diese drei Verben kann man aber auch als Vollverben verwenden:

> Erich **hat** Hunger.
> Irene **ist** Lehrerin.
> Barbara **wird** Polizistin.

---

Partizipien sind Mischwesen, die in der Welt zwischen Verben und Adjektiven leben. Sie haben Eigenschaften von beiden Welten und gehören doch nicht ganz zu dem einen oder anderen. Weil ich mir über den Status des Partizip II selbst nicht ganz sicher war, habe ich dazu vor 4 Jahren mal eine Frage gestellt: [Partizip II: Verb oder Adjektiv?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36241/partizip-ii-verb-oder-adjektiv)

Ich habe auf meine Frage zwar keine befriedigenden Antworten erhalten, aber meine weitere Recherche hat gezeigt, dass Partizipien zwar von Verben abgeleitet werden, aber nur mehr zum Teil selbst zu den Verben zu zählen sind. Am besten ist es, wenn man Partizipien als eigenständige Wortart betrachtet, die sehr eng mit Verben und Adjektiven verwandt ist.

Answer (score 0):

Partizipien sind infinite Verbformen (reiner Infinitv, Infinitiv mit zu, Partizip 1 und Partizip 2), diese Verformen hat jedes Voll-, Hilfs- und Modalverb, ob das dann verwendet wird, ist eine andere Frage.